# my svr-model doesn't work for another data

Tags: matlab

i have written a program that estimate image quality assessment.
in this code at first i extract some features from image and later sent them with their target value to an svm-train to make a model for regression. after making the model i call an image from my database and extract it's feature and send it to svm-predict to back value. this code work perfectly for my database and has very little error but dosen't work for another image out of my database and for any image back me the baias value.
what is the problem with my code?

Feature Extraction:

```
function f=feature_extraction (im)
addpath(genpath('.\features'));
tic
if size(im,3)==3
    im=rgb2gray(im);
end

f1=DOG_features(im);
f2=entropy_features(im);
f3=gradient_features(im);
f4=phasecong_features(im);

f=[f1 f2 f3 f4];

toc
(svr-mode:)
cost =16384 ;
gamma = 2;
c_str = sprintf('%f',cost);
g_str = sprintf('%.2f',gamma);
libsvm_options = ['-s 3 -t 2 -g ',g_str,' -c ',c_str];
model = svmtrain(target,f,libsvm_options);
```

after make model, I read an image like this:

```
im = imread('image.bmp');
f = feature_extraction(im);
quality = svmpredict(ones(1,1),f,model);
```

Comment: tl;dr You may get more responses/interest if you add a code sample :)

Comment: you mean my feature extraction code or regression code?

Comment: Whatever's relevant. In my experience, questions w/ code snippits and examples get answered faster and get more attention. -- Just giving helpful advice, not here to answer your question